# How can I put two CSS gradient backgrounds in one div?

Tags: css, gradient

I have the following CSS:

```css
.main {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)top;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)top; /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(229,229,229,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)))top; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)top; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)top; /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%) top; /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 )top; /* IE6-8 */
    background-size: Auto 200px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)bottom;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)bottom; /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(229,229,229,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)))bottom; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)bottom; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)bottom; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)bottom; /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%) bottom; /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 )bottom; /* IE6-8 */
    background-size: Auto 200px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-top: 50px;
    min-height:600px;
}
```

And here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtJmM/

I want that one gradient be at the top, and one at the bottom of the element. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use them in the same statement like:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,
                                       rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%) top, 
            linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,
                                       rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%) bottom;
```

Comment: Yes and no. These 4 lines will do the job in any browser that respect gradients without vendor prefixes. Currently I'm just sure Firefox does. But with vendor prefixes like in your example, using two `background-image`s (a gradient is nothing else to the browser) is possible in every browser that knows gradients (99% sure).

Comment: The problem is that in IE9 it doesn't work... How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try using it within one gradient statement? http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,c4c4c4+63,ffffff+64,c8c8c8+100;Custom